# Passing a variable to os.pathisfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have variables declared for a path to place a shortcut to the public desktop (code for that below)

```
SOURCE_PATH = r"\\ServerAddress\Installs\Software Package"
DEST_PATH = r"C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
FILE_NAME = "\\ProgramShortcut.lnk"


def place_shortcut():
    print("Placing Shortcut on Desktop..")
    shutil.copyfile(SOURCE_PATH + FILE_NAME, DEST_PATH + FILE_NAME)  #
```

I am looking to use those same variable(DEST_PATH and File_Name) to remove that same shortcut at the same spot - just to give you a idea what I am trying to do is basically the program will remove the icon/remove the program/reinstall program and then place the shortcut back using same variables. When I use the following code below it does not seem to do anything.

```
def remove_shortcut():
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DEST_PATH, FILE_NAME)):
        os.remove(os.path.join(DEST_PATH, FILE_NAME))
        print("Removing existing shortcuts")
```

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs about `os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component [that is, the second argument of the function] is an absolute path, *all previous components are thrown away* and joining continues from the absolute path component.

(Emphasis mine)

In your case, the call will be something like:

```
os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Public\Desktop", "\\ProgramShortcut.lnk")
```

*But* `"\\ProgramShortcut.lnk"` is an absolute path, so you'll end up checking the file `C:\ProgramShortcut.lnk`.

Comment: I see what you're saying here but its a complete separate function just wanting to make use of the variables again

Comment: @JasonLucas, this is impossible with the current values of these variables. A quick fix would be to do `FILE_NAME = "ProgramShortcut.lnk"`. `os.path.join` will put the necessary separators automatically.